# Finding $\cos(\pi/8)$ with half angle identities

Tags: trigonometry

I did $$\cos\left(\frac{45^\circ}{2}\right) = \sqrt{\frac{1 + \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}}{2}}$$ and ended by getting $\sqrt{\frac{2 + \sqrt{2}}{4}}$. But the answer in the book is $\frac{\sqrt{2 + \sqrt{2}}}{2}$.

Comment: the answers seem identical if you do some algebraic manipulation

Comment: You just didn't take the square root of the denominator, but the book did.

Comment: Oh ok. I see. thanks.

Comment: Please see this [tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: Will do, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\frac1{\sqrt2}=\cos\frac\pi4=\cos\left(2\frac\pi8\right)=\cos^2\frac\pi8-\sin^2\frac\pi8=2\cos^2\frac\pi8-1\implies$$

$$\cos\frac\pi8=\frac1{\sqrt2}\sqrt{\frac1{\sqrt2}+1}$$

Comment: Oh no!  Now there are 3 different answers!

Comment: Yes...but mine is correct. :)